# Need help in signing an Android application in Android Studio

Tags: java

I'm having an incredibly difficult time in Android Studio with signing my app.  I have tried a half dozen times, creating new certificates, to no avail.

The output from jarfile -verify is:

*This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is invalid. Reason: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate is self-signed.
This jar contains signatures that do not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after any of the signer certificates expire (as early as 2048-03-27).*

How can I correct this?